# Random numbers in a matrix which are divisible by 5 in R?

Tags: r, matrix, random, division

How can I write random numbers in a matrix which are divisible by 5 in R?
For instance,
20 20  85  45  55
5  15  20  90  10

Answer (score 1):

Generate some (20) random integers (say between 1 and 10):

```
x <- sample(1:10, size=20, replace=T)
```

Multiple those integers by 5

```
x <- x * 5
```

Put them in a matrix

```
x <- matrix(x, nrow=4, ncol=5)
```

---

Or do it all in one go:

```
 matrix(sample(1:10,20,T)*5, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

for example a matrix with 4 rows:

```
matrix(sample(seq(0,100,5),20, rep=T), 4)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   45   80   90   60    5
[2,]   95   35    0   15   65
[3,]   40   55   30   75   85
[4,]   70   20   50   10   25
```

Answer (score 0):

All the multiples of 5 in your range in a random order

```
set.seed(123)
sample(1:10)*5

matrix(sample(1:10)*5)
```

```
  [,1]
 [1,]   40
 [2,]   10
 [3,]   25
 [4,]   35
 [5,]   15
 [6,]   20
 [7,]    5
 [8,]   45
 [9,]   50
[10,]   30
```